# How to study distributed database system without produce and consume environment? linke Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, storage, distributed

Now, I want to research distributed storage or database system. but I have no produce and consume environment about above-mentioned subject.Could you give me some advice about how to create research an practice environment?

Comment: Yeah, it's a good idea, but how to emulate large concurrent access to see the performance of distributed system?

Answer (score 0):

Database systems research usually relies on standardized or commonly accepted benchmarks and distributed databases are no different. These specify workloads, in terms of what data, operations, and emulated clients, while providing a set of measurements that can be compared. The most well known and widely used are the [TPC benchmarks](http://www.tpc.org/), with multiple open source implementations for different database systems that you can easily deploy (e.g., the [OSDL DBT suite](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/osdldbt/index.php?title=Main_Page)). More recently, [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB) has been used a lot in NoSQL databases, in particular, for distributed systems.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any chance to apply for PhD about this research field?